# Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an eigenvector of the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ with eigenvalue $k$. Find a simple expression for $\mathbf{M}^n \mathbf{v}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an eigenvector of the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ with eigenvalue $k$. Find a simple expression for $\mathbf{M}^n \mathbf{v}$.

I'm not sure how to start with this. Should I test different values of matrices?

Comment: Have you tried to compute $M^2 v = M(Mv)$?

Comment: Thanks - I think I have the answer.

Comment: The problem statement should appear in the body of the Question.  The title does not have to be self-contained, but the body of the Question allows the full details to be spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Compute $M^2 v = M(Mv)$ and $M^3 v = M(M^2v)$. Can you see a pattern?